# Points warped when exporting to shape

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, ssf

I have recently purchased a Trimble GeoXH (used) and have done a few surveys. I have done differential correction in Trimble Pathfinder Office and all points seem fine.

When exporting to shape and other formats, all points is warped or compressed in Y-axis (and maybe X as well). Could this be a projection problem? Other solutions? I need to use the data in Qgis or similar.

Comment: What are you exporting (projection wise) too?

Comment: Exporting from corrected Trimble .ssf file (primarily point_generic with XYZ values) to *.shp to be imported in QuantumGIS or similar for generating contour model.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are stumbeling on the view of WGS84 lat/lon, which gets distorted the more to the poles you come.

Just set your **project** CRS to a projected CRS, for example EPSG:3857 (what Google Maps and Openstreetmap use) or the UTM zone for your part of the world, make sure that "on-the-fly-projection" is chekced, and the picture you see is similar to the maps you know.

Comment: Aha, I guessed this could be the problem but is it the raw file to be exported which need to be set with projected CRS or when importing in Qgis or similar?

Comment: The data from the GPS unit is most probably WGS84 lat/lon, so the layer should be set to that CRS(rightclick on the layer->Properties). The project CRS can be chosen differently (Settings->Project Settings) and should be in your case. EPSG:32632 (UTM 32N) should do well in Oslo.